# Excel VBA get time differences

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 cells with time data that format as follows:

```
"A1" = Sep 01 2018 00:01:33.707
"A2" = Sep 01 2018 00:01:49.917
```

I need to create a button and method within excel VBA that will set "A3" cell to true if the time "A2" is more than "A1" by 90 seconds.

Please help

Comment: Hi user1610208, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try,

[excel-formula](/questions/tagged/excel-formula)

```
=ABS(REPLACE(A1, 7, 0, ",")-REPLACE(A2, 7, 0, ","))>TIME(0, 0, 90)
```

Adding a simple comma should be enough for the overhead to calculate those das true datetimes when use mathematically.

[image]

[excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim str1 As String, str2 As String

    With Worksheets("sheet5")

        str1 = .Cells(1, "A").Text
        str2 = .Cells(2, "A").Text

        'greater than 90m seconds in A3
        .Cells(3, "A") = CBool(Abs((DateValue(Left(str1, 6) & "," & Mid(str1, 7, 5)) + _
                                    TimeValue(Mid(str1, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str1, 4))) - _
                                   (DateValue(Left(str2, 6) & "," & Mid(str2, 7, 5)) + _
                                   TimeValue(Mid(str2, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str2, 4)))) > _
                                   TimeSerial(0, 0, 90))
        'actual absolute difference in A4
        .Cells(4, "A") = Abs((DateValue(Left(str1, 6) & "," & Mid(str1, 7, 5)) + _
                                    TimeValue(Mid(str1, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str1, 4))) - _
                                   (DateValue(Left(str2, 6) & "," & Mid(str2, 7, 5)) + _
                                    TimeValue(Mid(str2, 13, 8)) + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) * CDbl(Right(str2, 4))))
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but I have to do this within an excel VBA function, I will need to use this function multiple times within a complex algorithm.

Comment: @user1610208 you specifically said you need to do this with a "button and a method" in your original question. Regardless, the approach outlined above *could* be modified to use as part of a UDF (VBA user-defined function) that could be used as part of a larger process/algorithm.

Comment: thanks @Jeeped , i have created and executed the Macro, but i get an error: runtime error: '13': type mismatch, within the 'greater than 90m seconds in A3' block

Comment: i have named the worksheet "sheet5", also when debugging these expressions seperately: Left(str1, 6) and Mid(str1, 7, 5) i get correct values, but the merged expression gives the error: DateValue(Left(str1, 6) & "," & Mid(str1, 7, 5))